# How to make a bootstrap button inset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I make a bootstrap 4 button look as if it's been clicked? I need someone with a little bit of artistic ability to add a drop shadow or inset or something.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary</a>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary active">active</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the active class.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary active">Primary</a>
```

From the documentation:

> Buttons will appear pressed (with a darker background, darker border,
>   and inset shadow) when active.

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2r67k42/1/) here as an example.

Comment: I don't know. I don't think that really connotes that it's been pressed down.

Comment: I am not sure what to say.  That is the "pressed" state for Bootstrap buttons, and what the documentation says.  If you want something else, you have to created your own CSS and then add that class yourself, possibly via Javascript if you have to.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a JSFiddle.  Maybe it's only because you have two buttons that it doesn't seem pressed to you?  It's obvious if there are more than one.

Comment: I just don't think it's obvious. It just doesn't look like a button that's been depressed. There should be a raised or lowered border. There should be some shadowing around the edges.

Comment: That is just the style because Bootstrap is using a more modern, "flat" style and not a 3D style where things would appear "sunk" as in having drop shadows, etc.    If you want to go that route, you'll just need to create custom CSS for it.   Here is an example that seems to be closer to what you're looking for:  http://callmenick.com/post/stylish-css-buttons ... see section 3 .. "Gradient & Shadow Style CSS Buttons (Skeumorphic)"